# Member function with default argument in variadic template class issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I have a variadic class template like this:

```
template<typename ... Args>
class myClass
{
public:
    void func(Args ... args, int a = 1)
    {}
};
```

And when I passing empty template argument,

```
myClass<> test;
test.func();
```

my MS compiler (vs2017) issued an error.

> error C2660: 'myClass<>::func': function does not take 0 arguments

And I also checked the corresponding function template version, like below.

```
template<typename ... Args>
void func(Args ... args, int a = 1)
{}
func<>();
```

But the compiler compiled with no error this time.

So I wonders am I violating c++11 standard or is this a bug in MS compiler because I have compiled this code with GCC before and compiler has no error.

Comment: No problem (compiling `test.func()`) with my g++ and my clang++; I suspect it's a MS bug.

Comment: Looks like something to bring up at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio